# How to create an array from an object which has several props as arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following structure

```
groups = {
 groupA: ["tag1","tag2","tag3"], //thousands of values
 groupB: ["tagA","tagB","tagC"], //thousands of values
 groupC: ["tag1A","tag2B","tag3C"] //thousands of values
}
```

and I need to reform it to something like this

```
tags = [{tag: 'tag1', group: 'groupA'}, {tag: 'tag2', group: 'groupA'}] //etc
```

Tried building this for a while, but can't seem to reach the result i need :/

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. A simple loop through the object -> Loop through the value array -> push an object to output array should work.

Comment: Why is there `groupC` when it isn't relevant for the end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const groups = {
  groups: {
    groupA: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    groupB: ["tagA", "tagB", "tagC"],
    groupC: ["tag1A", "tag2B", "tag3C"],
  },
};

const result = Object.entries(groups.groups)
  .map(([key, values]) => {
    return values.map((el) => ({ tag: el, group: key }));
  })
  .flat();

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let groups = {
  groupA: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"], //thousands of values
  groupB: ["tagA", "tagB", "tagC"], //thousands of values
  groupC: ["tag1A", "tag2B", "tag3C"], //thousands of values
};

let tags = [];
for (const g in groups) {
  for (const t of groups[g]) {
    tags.push({
      tag: t,
      group: g
    });
  }
}
console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
groups = {
  groupA: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
  groupB: ["tagA", "tagB", "tagC"],
  groupC: ["tag1A", "tag2B", "tag3C"], 
}
tags = [...groups.groupA.map(tag => ({
    tag,
    group: "groupA"
  })),
  ...groups.groupB.map(tag => ({
    tag,
    group: "groupB"
  })),
  ...groups.groupC.map(tag => ({
    tag,
    group: "groupC"
  }))
]

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a for in loop to capture the key
2. Run a for loop on every object to capture the tags.
3. Push it to a predefined array

```js
let groups = {
 groupA: ["tag1","tag2","tag3"], //thousands of values
 groupB: ["tagA","tagB","tagC"], //thousands of values
 groupC: ["tag1A","tag2B","tag3C"], //thousands of values
}

let altered = [];
for(var key in groups){
groups[key].forEach((tag)=>{
altered.push({
    group: key,
    tag:tag
  })
});
}


console.log(altered);
```